# Is it possible to obtain the coefficient of a specific term in a polynomial without calculating others'?

Tags: polynomials

Now I have a polynomial like this
$$f(x)=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(1+x^{a_i}\right)$$
where $a_i\in\mathbb{N}\,(i=1,2,\cdots,n)$. Let its expanded form be
$$f(x)=c_0+c_1x^1+c_2x^2+\cdots+c_tx^t\quad\left(t=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i\right)$$
I want to know the coefficient $c_s$ of a specific term $x^s\,(s\in\mathbb{N})$ in the expanded form of $f(x)$, without really expanding the formula, since the expanded formula would have up to $2^n$ terms, which is too large. I have considered the following approaches:

1. If we can find the $s$-order derivative of $f(x)$ at $x=0$, then the coefficient of $x^s$ would be $c_s=\frac{f^{(s)}(0)}{s!}$, but this approach seems not practical;
2. It is relatively easier to calculate the value of $f$ at some specific points, and we may use some interpolation methods to evaluate the coefficient $c_s$; but as far as I know, the methods like Lagrange interpolation and Newton's interpolation are not able to "only" evaluate $c_s$ without performing too much other calculations.

So is there a fast way to calculate $c_s$?

Note:

1. $a_i$ and $s$ might be very large, so it's not feasible to adopt a method which requires to calculate $c_0,\,c_1,\,\cdots,\,c_s$.
2. There isn't a specific definition of "fast" here, but I'm generally looking for an approach more "clever" than simply expanding the formula. It would be the best if we can calculate $c_s$ by pen and paper when $n$ and each $a_i$ are as large as $1000$, but if there doesn't exist any approach that fast, any approach that is faster than expanding the formula would be accepted.
3. It is trivial that when $s=0$, $c_s=2^k$, where $k$ is the number of $a_i$ equal to zero; when $s>t$, we know that $c_s=0$. So we only need to consider the case that $0<s\le t$.

Comment: Another way to isolate a specific coefficient is through contour integration (the Cauchy integral formula that calculates derivatives).

Comment: Well you have the formula $c_s = \#\left\lbrace J \subset \lbrace 1, \ldots, n \rbrace, \sum_{j \in J} a_j = s\right\rbrace$. But without more specifications, it's hard to tell what's a "fast" way to calculate $c_s$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Zag's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4606832/is-it-possible-to-obtain-the-coefficient-of-a-specific-term-in-a-polynomial-with#comment9707606_4606832) mentions, we have $$c_s = \#\left\lbrace J \subset \lbrace 1, \ldots, n \rbrace, \sum_{j \in J} a_j = s\right\rbrace.$$

Note that determining whether $c_s$ is nonzero is precisely the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is known to be NP-complete.

For practical pen-and-paper computations, I would probably use dynamic programming (e.g. see answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305843/find-all-subsets-that-sum-to-a-particular-value)); more sophisticated methods could be adapted from the vast literature on the closely related [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

For impractical purposes, you can evaluate at roots of unity to isolate a particular coefficient:

For any $m > t$ and $\zeta = e^{2\pi i/m}$,
$$c_s = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{f(\zeta^k)}{(\zeta^k)^s}.$$
(For proof, note that $c_s$ is the constant coefficient of $f(x)/x^s$. Summing over all the $m$th roots of unity will leave only the terms with exponent divisible by $m$, so for $m$ large enough we get the desired coefficient.)

This is a discrete version of the Cauchy integral formula mentioned in [Greg Martin's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4606832/is-it-possible-to-obtain-the-coefficient-of-a-specific-term-in-a-polynomial-with#comment9707363_4606832).

There's also the number-theoretic version:
$$c_s \equiv -\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\frac{f(k)}{k^s} \pmod{p}$$
for any prime $p > t$.

Comment: Do you mean $c_s=\frac{1}{m}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{f\left(e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{m}}\right)}{{\left(e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{m}}\right)}^s}$?

Comment: @Soha Fixed, thanks.